# Creating a variable length string of whitespaces in Mathematica

Tags: regex, wolfram-mathematica

The following Mathematica function f creates a string of whitespace of length n.

```
f[n_]:=Fold[StringJoin,"",Array[" "&,n]]
```

There must be a zillion alternatives to create this function.

How would you have done it?

Comment: The version with `Fold` that you quoted is actually one of the worst ways to do this performance-wise, since it will have quadratic in `n` performance for large enough `n`. This string concatenation problem is language-agnostic. In Java, for example,  `StringBuffer` and `StringBuilder` classes were introduced specifically to avoid this overhead. In Mathematica, `StringJoin` with multiple arguments (like in some of the answers you received) is also quite efficient and is a better solution.

Comment: Using `Array` the 4-argument signature `Array[" "&,n,1,StringJoin]` is the way to go, but this is inferior, performance-wise, than other methods suggested.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
f[n_] := StringJoin @ ConstantArray[" ", n]
```

**Edit:** since @ is as idiomatic as @@ and a bit faster (thanks to Mr.Wizard for benchmarking) and shorter i updated the solution.

Comment: I'd just like to point out that `StringJoin @ ConstantArray[" ", n]` works too. (Since it's not intuitive that it should.)

Comment: Yeah, i also noticed that both variants are possible but i tried to make the solution concise and idiomatic and thought changing the head to StringJoin was the more idiomatic alternative. In terms of speed and lowlevel-ness i like Sjoerds solution.

Answer (score 5):

```
f[n_] := FromCharacterCode[ConstantArray[32, {n}]]
```

By the way: you should be aware that this type of question is frowned upon in the [faq](https://stackoverflow.com/faq):

> What kind of questions should I not ask here?
>
> You should only ask practical,
>   answerable questions based on actual
>   problems that you face. Chatty,
>   open-ended questions diminish the
>   usefulness of our site and push other
>   questions off the front page. To
>   prevent your question from being
>   flagged and possibly removed, avoid
>   asking subjective questions where …
>
> ```
> 1. every answer is equally valid: “What’s your favorite ______?”
> ```

Don't be surprised if the question is closed.

Comment: Refactoring theorists would say that 32 has a smell, while quite some Java code style checkers wouldn't accept the 32 either. I would like it if there was a named constant for 32.

Comment: @user763851 you could use `ToCharacterCode[" "] // First` for that.

Comment: @user763851 I'd go one step further and say that lots of "code smells" themselves are artifacts of languages for which refactoring theories are big, since "theories" indicate to me lots of protocols and not enough support for good abstractions. Refactoring should not necessarily be a separate step, the language should allow you to refactor code as you write it, or to write generic code from the start. The good news is that Mathematica does.

Comment: ( About refactoring. Have you ever had to change BAD code ( say 100,000K++ lines ) you didn't write in the first place? ) - Do you mean that there are languages that do not facilitate Writing generic code from the start? Perhaps I missed your point there.

Comment: @ndroock1 I worked with commercial Java projects (software for large banks) of about 3000 classes or so (I was a lead developer on a sub-project), out of which several hundred classes I wrote myself,  and yes, I was doing many large-scale refactorings (hundreds classes affected at a time). And I must say that lots of bad code was due to Java weaknesses (verbose,no decent support for closures, no parametric polymorphism, no type inference, etc). Once I  refactored the code to use functional-style programming (immutable objects, generics, proper use of interfaces), it became much more managable.

Comment: @ndroock1 Continuing... Yet, my impression was that Java the language was responsible for much of the generated complexity I had to deal with. Even when you use the best available idioms, it is not expressive enough for my taste. Sure, if you are given a large existing codebase, refactoring is one of the best things you can do, but I wouldn't start a new project in Java (given excellent JVM alternatives such as Scala or Clojure). Regarding generic code, I think languages without support for closures, higher order functions, etc, do not encourage it, and generics is too weak of a substitute.

Answer (score 3):

```
f[n_] := StringJoin[Table[" ", {n}]]
```

Answer (score 2):

`Spacer` and `Invisible` are also be useful for creating whitespace, with differences in how you specify the size of the space.

Comment: Thanks. Just learned two new Mathematica statements. ;-) ( I have used Mathematica mostly as a mathematics workbench. )

Answer (score 2):

```
f = ConstantArray[" ", #] <> "" &;
```

<del>This is about twice as fast as Thies Heidecke's function,</del> but not nearly as fast as Sjoerd's.

---

For large `n` a longer initial string is helpful.  This is faster than Sjoerd's method for `n > 10000`:

```
f2ss = " "~ConstantArray~499 <> "";
f2[n_ /; n < 500] := StringTake[f2ss, n]
f2[n_ /; n < 5000] := StringTake[ConstantArray["          ", ⌈n/10⌉] <> "", n]
f2[n_] := StringTake[ConstantArray[f2@400, ⌈n/400⌉] <> "", n]
```

Comment: yeah, I should have remarked that I chose my solution for speed. It's about 5.5 times as fast as Thies' solution. But then, you need strings in the order of 100 million characters to appreciate the difference.

Comment: @Sjoerd it appears a modified `StringJoin` method is faster than `FromCharacterCode` on large `n`.

Comment: @Sjoerd "strings in the order of 100 million characters" only take a few lifetimes to print. ;-)

Comment: @ndroock1 true, and my second function `f2` is more to satisfy my own curiosity.  The first function `f` however it concise and plenty fast.  If you prefer Thies' code for some reason, realize that it will be about twice as fast if you replace `@@` with `@`.

Comment: @ndrock1 Well, since we're discussing spaces it shouldn't be that difficult. Your paper comes pre-printed with them ;-)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard oh, if i had known that the @ variant is twice as fast i'd probably used that in the first place. I think i'll update my answer