# two questions on string manipulation in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

1. Given a character or a string `s`, generate a result string with `n` (an integer) repeats of `s`
2. Given a list of characters or strings, and a list of the frequencies of their appearance (in correspondence), generate a result string with each string in the list repeated with the desired times as specified in the second list and StringJoin them together. For example, given `{"a", "b", "c"}` and `{1,0,3}`, I want to have `"accc"`.

I of course want to have the most efficient way of doing these. Otherwise, my own way is too ugly and slow.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6082172/creating-a-variable-length-string-of-whitespaces-in-mathematica/6082260#6082260

Comment: Is the second question because of my answer to the combinations question?  I almost included the `MapThread` code in that post, but I decided not to.  Should I have?

Comment: Mr. Wizard, exactly as you guessed. :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
rep[s_String, n_] := StringJoin[ConstantArray[s, n]]
```

then

```
rep["f", 3]
(*fff*)
```

next

```
chars = {"a", "b", "c"};
freqs = {1, 0, 3};

StringJoin[MapThread[rep, {chars, freqs}]]
```

gives "accc"

Comment: I was doing `Nest[StringJoin[s,#]&,"",n]`, of course slower than the built-ins!

Comment: @Qiang Li Using `Nest` in this context is analogous to using `AppendTo` for list-building, and leads to the similar quadratic complexity of the solution. This is the main reason for the slowness, not the departure from built-ins per se.

Comment: There's a flaw, it should be `s_String` not `s__String`; `ConstantArray` will get mad if you pass it more than one string at a time.

Comment: @rcollyer thanks, luck on my part to get the answer first! (the __ was indeed a typo, fixed, thanks)

Comment: yeah, I spent my time linking to the relevant docs, if I hadn't, the answer would have been mine! :P And, I would have still thought I had more than 5k rep ... :(

Answer (score 5):

For 1, `Table` will do what you need.

```
s = "samplestring";

  StringJoin[Table[s, {3}]]

  "samplestringsamplestringsamplestring"
```

But acl's answer using `ContantArray` is faster, if you care about the last 1/100th second.

```
Do[StringJoin[Table[s, {30}]];, {10000}] // Timing

{0.05805, Null}

Do[StringJoin[ConstantArray[s, 30]];, {10000}] // Timing

{0.033306, Null}

Do[StringJoin[Table[s, {300}]];, {10000}] // Timing

{0.39411, Null}

Do[StringJoin[ConstantArray[s, 300]];, {10000}] // Timing

{0.163103, Null}
```

For 2, MapThread will handle cases where the second list is known to be non-negative integers.

```
StringJoin @ 
 MapThread[Table[#1, {#2}] &, {{"a", "b", "c"} , {1, 0, 3}}]

"accc"
```

If the second list contains negative integers, these are treated as zeros.

Non-integer elements in the second list are treated as if they are the integer part. I am not sure if this is what you want.

```
StringJoin @ 
 MapThread[Table[#1, {#2}] &, {{"a", "b", "c"} , {1, 0, 3.7}}]

"accc"
```

Answer (score 2):

[Knowing your application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8145710/generate-all-combintations-for-list-with-repeated-items/8166724#8166724) I propose using `Inner`:

```
sets = {{0, 0, 0, 4}, {0, 0, 1, 3}, {0, 1, 0, 3}, {0, 1, 1, 2}, {0, 2, 0, 2},
        {0, 2, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 0, 3}, {1, 0, 1, 2}, {1, 1, 0, 2}, {1, 1, 1, 1},
        {1, 2, 0, 1}, {1, 2, 1, 0}, {2, 0, 0, 2}, {2, 0, 1, 1}, {2, 1, 0, 1},
        {2, 1, 1, 0}, {2, 2, 0, 0}};

chars = {"a", "b", "c", "d"};

Inner[ConstantArray[#2, #] &, sets, chars, StringJoin]
```

```
{"dddd", "cddd", "bddd", "bcdd", "bbdd", "bbcd", "addd", "acdd",
"abdd", "abcd", "abbd", "abbc", "aadd", "aacd", "aabd", "aabc", "aabb"}
```